# Dart Sockets, how to await for a response

Tags: dart, sockets

I am using dart:io and Socket class.
What I'm trying to do:

1. send a frame
2. get the response
3. check if the response has a flag to stop
4. flag = true?  ->  stop this proccess
5. flag = false?  ->  go to step 1 (yes, infinite loop until user manually cancel)

The problem:
These steps are inside a Future.doWhile, and socket.listen get not be called until I stop this while.

The solution:
Changed Future.doWhile by "Complete() + Timer.periodic"
As Timer.periodic does not allow await, so I created a Complete() variable to await for.

My question is:  Am I doing this using the best pratices?
It is very difficult/confusing to work with sockets when I need to wait for the frame's response and on top of that wait for the frame to have the flag I need to finish...

Comment: It would be really helpful to have the actual code posted in your question.